# jquery fading effect not working

Tags: jquery

The following code with Jquery is not working.  The divison is not fading -out. Kindly help me

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
#fade{    background-color:#abc123;    width:200px;  height:30px; padding:3px; }
</style>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#animate").click(function() {
    $("#fade").animate(
            {"width": "200px"},
            "fast");
});
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="fade">Animate Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, where is `#animate`? Next, fading out changes the element opacity but not width, and can be done with `fadeOut()`. Last, don't forget about DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 2):

Any DOM-referencing jQuery needs to be enclosed in a document ready handler (DRH). Also, you are not fading the DIV but simply animating on its dimensions.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#animate").click(function() {
```

or simply

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#animate").click(function() {
```

...otherwise you're attempting to talk to DOM elements before the DOM is actually ready.

[EDIT - as other answers have noted, there is no `#animate` element. This is likely to be another cause of the problem, though the above issue still remains.]

Comment: could you furnish the full code please? as I am unable to check in the explorer

Answer (score 1):

There is no `#animate` element in your example!

If you change you code like this it will work just fine:

```
$("#fade").click(function() {
    $("#fade").animate(
            {"width": "200px"},
            "fast");
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8C7Yh/)

Comment: Might as well use `$(this)` inside the callback rather than make jQuery look up the element again.

Comment: @Utkanos I know that, but I wanted to make it work with least changes

Comment: Thank your response. The code is not working.  Could you provide the total HTML please?

Comment: Sir, I want call back, when the mouse is out

Answer (score 0):

The .animate call you are using won't fade the div, but will try to animate a width change. To fade the block do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fade").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    });

    $("#fade").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

EDIT: Updated with complete example including mouseout.